# In quali regioni si usa "sporta" al posto di "busta"?

Tags: regional

In Emilia, ma anche in Romagna, sento parlare di 'sporte' e di 'sportine' piuttosto che di 'buste' e di 'bustine'.

Sapreste dire in quali altre regioni il termine 'sporta', con il significato di 'busta', generalmente quella usata per la spesa al mercato, è pienamente compreso?

Cioè, in quali regioni posso dire 'mi dia una sporta' senza che mi rispondano 'cosaaaa!'?

Comment: Al mio orecchio romano suona comprensibile ma insolito, mentre credo che sia piuttosto diffuso anche in Toscana.

Comment: Veramente credo che "sporta" sia la versione più vecchia, forse ormai considerata obsoleta quindi la domanda sarebbe: dov'è anche ancora si usa normalmente?

Comment: L'ho solo sentito nell'espressione "un sacco e una sporta".

Comment: Sono del sud e non ho mai sentito la parola 'sporta', da noi si usa la parola 'busta di plastica'

Comment: @antman79 non so di dove sei, ma a Napoli *Tiene cchiù' corna tu che 'na sporte 'e maruzze* fa chiaramente riferimento ad una borsa piena di lumache.

Comment: Qui, nel ponente ligure, sporta si usa da sempre.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A giudicare dalla [voce sul dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/busta/), sbaglia chi usa *busta* per il sacchetto o la borsa della spesa. Il [Sabatini-Coletti concorda](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/B/busta.shtml).

Dunque *busta* e *sporta* non sono affatto sinonimi. Chiedere una busta, alla cassa di un supermercato in Veneto, avrebbe come conseguenza almeno uno sguardo perplesso. La parola *sporta* è tuttavia percepita come dialettale in Veneto, perché è l'unica usata in dialetto per “il contenitore della spesa”.

A spanne direi che l'uso di *busta* per *sporta* o *sacchetto* è meridionale; là si dice anche *bustone* per *sacco* (della spazzatura, per esempio).

Comment: Idem per Friuli.

Comment: Quindi è per colpa di veneti e friulani che ora tutti usano shopper?!? :)

Comment: @N74 Molti veneti tendono a considerare certe parole come dialettali e *sporta* è una di queste (c'è di mezzo anche la locuzione *un sacco e una sporta*, credo), quindi cercano di evitarla quando parlano italiano.

Comment: Però, se *busta* non è compreso e *sporta* è considerato dialettale, non ci hai ancora detto qual è il termine usato correntemente in Veneto.

Comment: @N74 Sacchetto, per quello di plastica ormai comunemente chiamato *shopper*.

Answer (score 3):

In Lombardia lo si usa parecchio.
Io ho origini liguri ed adesso abito in Lombardia. A Genova non avevo mai sentito sporta, ho sempre usato sacchetto (anche "busta" la prima volta che lo sentii mi suonava strano poiché per me le buste sono solo quelle delle lettere). Penso quindi di poterti dire con ragionevole certezza che in lombardia (o almeno in valtellina) si usa :)

Comment: A Milano non l'ho mai sentito...

Answer (score 3):

Confermo che "sporta" è usato quotidianamente in Emilia e in Romagna e, per mia esperienza, spesso compreso nel Veneto meridionale, probabilmente in virtu dei rapporti con la regione confinante.

Di certo non è comune nelle regioni del Sud: mi è capitato più di una volta, in coda alla cassa in un supermercato di Ferrara, di trovarmi dietro a studenti pugliesi rimasti attoniti alla domanda della cassiera "Vuoi una sportina?". :)

Answer (score 0):

Sicuramente non utilizzato in Veneto, dove la forma più usata mi risulta essere *borsa*, forse originariamente per ipercorrezione, né in Sardegna o in Calabria, dove si dice *busta*.

Quindi mi pare rimangano piene di *sporte* solo Toscana, Emilia-Romagna e Lombardia.

Comment: Non sono per niente d'accordo. Io sono trentino ed ho studiato in provinia di Vicenza. In entrambe le province si usa prevalentemente sporta.

Comment: Sporta è sicuramente usato in Veneto (area di Treviso/Venezia), anche se ho l'impressione che stia cadendo in disuso tra le generazioni più giovani. Coloro che parlano principalmente in dialetto la usano regolarmente